# Java JDBC types and code snippets

Tags: java, database, jdbc, connection, drivers

There are four types of JDBC Drivers.

1. JDBC-ODBC
2. JDBC-NATIVE
3. JDBC-NETWORK
4. PURE JAVA (Without middleware)

My Question is if JDBC-ODBC driver uses:

```
Class.forname("sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver");
```

Then what can be use for other three driver types..??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are not "other three drivers", these are driver **types**. The other JDBC types require a vendor implementation of a JDBC driver. For example for Firebird the driver Jaybird (which I maintain) provides both a type 2 and type 4 implementation to access Firebird. Similarly, Oracle also has a JDBC driver that provides both a type 2 and a type 4 implementation to access Oracle. Most databases provide at least a type 4 driver.

Type 3 drivers are relatively rare (or at least: last time I've seen/used one was +/- 10 years ago), but they involve a driver part and a middleware server.

Note that the type 1 driver `sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver` has been removed from Java 8 and is no longer available.

Comment: Any example snippets of rest of three drivers would be helpful.

Comment: @JᴀʏᴅᴇᴠSʜɪʀᴏʏᴀ I think you fail to understand how JDBC works: JDBC is an interface specification, and each driver implements that interface. There are more than three other drivers (at least one for the common database systems), however in all cases JDBC works the same: you talk to the same API, with - assuming the driver correctly implemented the specification - the same way of using it. The driver types are in most aspects irrelevant for the end-user (except that type 2 requires a native dependency, and type 3 will require the installation of the middleware server).

Comment: @JᴀʏᴅᴇᴠSʜɪʀᴏʏᴀ Your question only suggests that you haven't read this answer.